# Cell fracture - setting the start/end points of animation

Tags: animation

I'm making a sequence showing how a tunnel collapsed into an old one beneath it. I've been following tutorials and experimenting with Cell Fracture to do the part where the top tunnel collapses down. That's great and I like the effects, but the problem is that it's part of a longer sequence of 800 frames, and I need this short sequence to start at frame 400 and run for 100 frames.

All the tutorials I've watched don't seem to mention how to control the start / end frame numbers. Could I ask for some assistance please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can keyframe the *Animated* option of one of the objects, if the object has *Animated* on, it won't follow the physics. Then later on the *Timeline*, switch it off and keyframe again:

[image]

Once you've keyframed one of the objects, select all the other objects, make sure that the one with the action is the active one, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Animation Data*.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!! It's so easy when you know how to do it! It's working just right, so you've really made my day!

Comment: OK - slight problem :( I've run this on a trial with just the cylinder I'm trying to collapse and the technique works. Select a piece, click animate and keyframe. Them move to later and click off animate and keyframe. As expected the selected piece drops at the correct frame, link animation data and all works. However, in my cityscape I can select one piece and keyframe as above and it will stay in place, but wont drop when animate is turned off. I've turned off visibility for all surrounding objects to avoid affecting other objects. Sorry for the total newb question!

Comment: maybe share just one of your object so that we can see why it doesn't work?

Comment: OK - how do I do that?

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload.com

Comment: OK will do but will be later one. Thanks!

Comment: I made a version with everything stripped out apart from the cylinders to upload, and blow me down the animation works as I want. I guess it's a process of elimination to see what's interfering with the animation?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening, hard to tell without any file

Comment: OK. I have spent time eliminating things, and I know where the problem lies. In the timeline, if I add the start and end animate keyframes adjacent to each other  it works well. However, move the end keyframe past two others it stops working. The two others are to do with controlling camera speed. I'm uploading the file shortly.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G0x-lK3QGXZIdMSNuo1_bLrAu204B09X/view?usp=sharing shows the keyframes. The orange one at 300 frames woks if you put it before  the frame 150 one, and stops working after it.

Comment: If you mean that the rigid body stops to work, maybe it's because your cache stops at frame 150? In Scene panel > Rigid Body World > Cache > Simulation End. If it's not your problem, please share your file

Comment: Brilliant - that's it! By changing the simulation end to 750 that allows me to put the animate off point to 500 (where I want it) and the whole thing collapses. I don't seem to be able to share the file as maybe my privilege level is not high enough yet, but I can't thank you enough for your help and support here! happy new year :)

Comment: great, happy new year to you too   ;)